# Extracting Substring from string using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, string, string-formatting

I have collection of batch numbers coming into the system(e.g 24132352454235000534) that are each 20 characters long. I would like to, using regular expression, extract, say the substring from 7 to 15, from each of my batch numbers.

The reason I would like to use regular expressions is that the requirement is not to modify the existing code which is used by over 20 processes, but simply add the expression to the configuration so that it can be applied when needed by the right process.

How would I go about doing this please?

Comment: Could you please provide an example output and format your question to be more human readable? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=\d{6})\d{8}
```

See it here in action: http://regex101.com/r/eX5rZ9

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
(\d{6})(\d{9})(\d{5})
```

Sample code:

```
string strRegex = @"(\d{6})(\d{9})(\d{5})";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"24132352454235000534";
string strReplace = @"$2";  // corresponds to the 2nd group: (\d{9})

return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```

Final string:

```
524542350
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the expression is doing please?

Comment: @Kobojunkie - it is looking ahead 6 digits (\d{6}), capturing the next 9 digits (\d{9}) and ignoring the last 5 digits(\d{5}).

Comment: Thanks for providing the explanation @Brian, you were faster than me :)

Comment: @Brian: "looking ahead 6 digits" and "ignoring the last 5 digits" is misleading.  You make it sound like he's using lookarounds, when in fact he's *capturing* all three chunks.

Comment: @AlanMoore - You are 100% correct, Alan.  I just didn't want to potentially confuse the OP, who seems new to `Regular Expressions`.

Comment: Just FYI, the `Multiline` and `Singleline` options are having no effect.

Comment: @AlanMoore: you're right, for this particular example they don't make a difference. That code was generated by .NET regex Hero, that's what I use to test .NET regular expressions: http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: Yeah, RegexBuddy does that, too.  I find it easiest to leave all options unselected and use inline modifiers like `(?i)` and `(?m)` when I really need them.